# How to fix: KeyError: "None of [Index([...], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I'm a beginner/Student and want to develop a prototype for a neural Network.
I want to create a variable from a DataFrame-column, but I get an error I do not understand:

```
# take() does not accept boolean indexers
KeyError: "None of [Index(['Solar - Actual Aggregated [MW]'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

I have seen a post which said that spaces in the column name are not good, but in the past I did not had a Problem with that.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("...Test_Trainingsdaten/03.06.19/Produziert%20Solar%20Wind_28-06-19.csv")

df.info()
# MTU                               96 non-null object
# Solar - Actual Aggregated [MW]    96 non-null int64


X = df[["MTU"]].values                               # works                 
Y = df[["Solar - Actual Aggregated [MW]"]].values    # error
```

With those two variables i wanted to create a simple machine learning model, but I don't know how to fix that error

Comment: If I google this error, I see lots of questions on Stack Overflow with similar titles. Have you checked any of them?

Comment: Yes I did, but I couldn't find something useful, or I'm just not smart enough

Comment: what does `print(df.columns.tolist())` show?

Comment: ['area', 'mtu', 'solar__-_actual_aggregated_[mw]', 'wind_offshore__-_actual_aggregated_[mw]', 'wind_onshore__-_actual_aggregated_[mw]']

Comment: I used a command i found online: df.columns = df.columns.str.strip().str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', ''), it changed my column Name to: solar__-actual_aggregated_[mw], now it works to create the variable